# How to limit iOS button title with 0 lines in background area?

Tags: ios, swift, button

[image: Example]

As above picture, the blue area is the button, but the title with 0 lines is out of the area, also I tried that set the titleLabel frame with the frame with the button, but still it does not work, so any tips here??

Comment: set number of line 1 or 2 instead of 0

Comment: please describe what are you trying to achieve? Button with multiple lines?

Comment: I need a flexible text area...

Comment: actually I need a flexible frame button, and the text on button should show itself as more as possible from left and top but limited to the bottom bounds

Comment: Ok, posted an answer below, hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Clip the content to bounds:

```
myButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help:

1) add a button

2) set line break (see screen)

3) set multimple lines in text (use alt+enter to new line )

[image]

4) Set constraints for leading and for top - so width and height can be calculated by autolayout

5) set background color if you need

[image]